# Searching Content Inside of Pictures and Scans?

Tags: unity, scopes

I'm pretty exciting by the "scopes" within Ubuntu to search.

However, I've had trouble finding any concrete answers on the following.

I love using Evernote and Google Drive because they both search inside of pictures and scans for content. For instance, if I get a letter from the doctor that I want to keep, I will usually scan it and save it to Evernote. If I need that letter 5 years from now, I can just search for terms that were in that scan, and viola, it is there. I would like to find a way of doing this on a local system so that I don't have so much stuff in the cloud.

Is there a way of turning Unity and Scopes into a form of Evernote? Are there programs out there that will search for text inside of images and store that information in metadata for a Ubuntu Scope search?